# Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). - Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have been trying to implement a simple ngFor with Angular2 but I don't know what went wrong which lead to error 'Generic TYpe Array requires one argument(s). PLease favour

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl:'./app.component.html',                     
    })
    export class AppComponent { 
           clients:Array;
           doctors:Array;
            constructor(){
               this.clients=["Client1", "Client2", "Client3"];
                this.doctors=["Doctor1","Doctor2","Doctor3"];
            }


    }
```

Comment: Read Generics Concept in programming first

Answer (score 39, accepted):

solution 1:

```
clients: String[]; // if type cant be determined use 'any[]'
    doctors: String[];
```

solution 2:

```
clients: Array<String>; // if type cant be determined use '<any>'
    doctors: Array<String>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Angular2, but I believe the solution, since you know the type which the array is going to hold, is to use `Array<String>` instead of array on its own.

**NOTE:** what you could do is replace `String` with the angular2 typename for a string primitive.